# Security, touchid and password problems on my MacBook M1

Tags: macbook-pro, keychain, apple-silicon

After I got problem with the keychain and reset it I have the following issues on my MacBook that I have not been succeeding to fix:

1. TouchId does is not activated. When I try to activate/set up in System Preference I get "Authenitcation Cancelled"

The first try, clicked "Unlocking your Mac" requires password. When I provide that nothing happens after and I get the above message when trying other option in the same panel.

2. In the "Sequrity & Privacy" panel I try, after knocking the panel, to change "Require password  to <15 minutes>. I can click the 15 min but it is immediately changed back to .
3. Creating cloud now ask for password very often

All this was not a problem before I reset the keychain.

I would appreciate any help on this very annoying topic.